# Elastic search query is not executed

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am using elastic search engine to search for some items, items are placed in some buildings, when running this query, Items returned are not sorted even if I change the sort direction. My first impression is that the block sort is not even executed. Is there something wrong with the query ?

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "buildingsUuid": [
              "9caff147-d019-416a-a167-f02bab7334fd"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "itemId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share the mapping. Also which version of ES would this be?

Comment: mapping would be helpful, id itemId a multi-value array?